# Why is the connection not identical in all of my methods?

Tags: jakarta-ee, connection, ejb

I'm on a training about JAVA EE and we were talking about Connection Pooling. Adam Bien writes in his book "*Real World Java EE Patterns-Rethinking Best Practices*" that in a JAVA EE application the container handles one database connection for every module. To proof this we used the two EJB you see below.

**MainBean**

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MainBean implements MainBeanRemote {

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/sample")
    DataSource dataSource1;

    @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/sample")
    DataSource dataSource2;

    @EJB
    HelperBean hb;

    public void taking2ConnectionsFromThePool() {
        try {
            Connection con1 = dataSource1.getConnection();
            Connection con2 = dataSource1.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void taking1ConnectionEachFrom2DataSources() {
        try {
            Connection con1 = dataSource1.getConnection();
            Connection con2 = dataSource2.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    public void compareMainBeanWIthHelperBean() {
        try {
            Connection con1 = dataSource1.getConnection();
            Connection con2 = hb.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // ...
        }
    }

}
```

**HelperBean:**

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class HelperBean {
     @Resource(lookup = "jdbc/sample")
    private DataSource dataSource2;

    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        return dataSource2;
    }
     public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
         Connection con = dataSource2.getConnection();
        return con;
    }

}
```

When we debuged the three functions we noticed the following things:

1. In function `taking2ConnectionsFromThePool` both connections are identical as expected.
2. The same in `taking1ConnectionEachFrom2DataSources`.

So far so good, but

3. In the `compareMainBeanWIthHelperBean` function the connection of `con1` and inside the `HelperBean` were identical (as expected) but the connection of `con2` was different.

When I asked my docent why in this case the connection is different he didn't know. Can anyone explain me why in the last function the connection is different?

P.S. I know that the third method isn't a real situation but per Adam Bien in all cases the connection should be identical and this was why we wrote the three methods in the training.

P.P.S: We used the current glassfish application server and Java (JDA and JRE) (u77)

Comment: Maybe you got two proxies referencing a unique physical connection. What's the type of both connections?

Comment: JDBC connections to the java build in derby database, configured in the glassfish application server

Comment: That doesn't tell me their type. What is the result of connection.getClass()?

Comment: @JBNizet I again checked the debug information: Type is in all cases `NetConnection40` but value is different.